# JavaScript: How to set a parent object as a parameter within an addEventListener function?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

how can I set the object (which is part of the buttons array) as a parameter within the addEventListener function? buttons[i] is not working..

Here is a part of the code:

```
var buttonNames = ["canteen","locations","floorplan","guestbook","pictures"];
    var buttonDivNames = ["btn1","btn2","btn3","btn4","btn5"];
    var buttons = [];

    window.onload = function() {

        for(var i = 0; i<buttonNames.length; i++) {
            var obj = new Object();
            obj.targetLink = buttonNames[i] + ".html";
            obj.defaultImage = "img/buttons/"+buttonNames[i]+"_default.jpg";
            obj.hoverImage = "img/buttons/"+buttonNames[i]+"_hover.jpg";
            obj.div = document.getElementById(buttonDivNames[i]);
            obj.divPicture = obj.div.getElementsByClassName("thumbnailPicture")[0];
            obj.divLink = obj.div.getElementsByClassName("thumbnailLink")[0];
            buttons.push(obj);
        }

        for(var i = 0; i<buttons.length; i++) {
            buttons[i].divPicture.addEventListener("mouseover",function() { anotherFunction(buttons[i]) },false)
        }

    }

    function anotherFunction(arg) {
        console.log(arg.targetLink);
    }
```

Thanks guys, this way it works:

```
        for(var i = 0; i<buttons.length; i++) {
            initButton(buttons[i]);
        }

    }

    function initButton(arg) {
        arg.divPicture.addEventListener("mouseover",function() {anotherFunction(arg);},false)
    }

    function anotherFunction(arg) {
        console.log(arg.targetLink);
    }
```

Comment: Your use of buttons[i] as a parameter within a loop is not adequate, You will find all the eventlisteners are using the same button.
You can fix this by immediately calling a new function with button[i] as its argument, and then add the eventlistener there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment section, you could use an IIFE to create a new scope, that holds the value of the current `i`:

```
for(var i = 0; i<buttons.length; i++) {
    (function (i) {
        buttons[i].divPicture.addEventListener("mouseover",function() { anotherFunction(buttons[i]) },false)
    }(i));
}
```

or, even better, create a seperate function that handles the adding of the eventlistener:

```
function addEventlistenerToButton(button) {
    button.divPicture.addEventListener("mouseover",function() { anotherFunction(button) },false)
}

// ....
for(var i = 0; i<buttons.length; i++) {
    addEventlistenerToButton(buttons[i]);
}
```

In addition to that, you could also omit sending the button to the eventlistener completely and get the button from the event object directly:

```
for(var i = 0; i<buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].divPicture.addEventListener("mouseover", anotherFunction, false);
}

function anotherFunction(ev) {
    ev = ev || window.event;
    var src = ev.target || ev.srcElement;

    console.log(src.parentNode);
}
```